# How to display only 1 post from certain category with certain params "true"

Tags: hugo

The idea is how to display only 1 latest post from certain category if it has params featured "true"

```
{{ range (where .Data.Pages "Type" "blog") 1 }}  
{{ if and (in .Params.categories "photography") (in .Params.featured "true") }}
```

the code above is working but it render all the posts with category **foo** (more than 1 post)

```
    {{ $photography := .Data.Pages.ByParam "categories"  }}
    {{ if and (in .Params.featured "true") (eq .Params.categories "photography") }}
       {{ range first 1 $photography }}
```

the code above have no errors but it doesnt render at all

any clue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way to solve this based on how `categories` is defined.

### Solution (categories as a taxonomy)

In this case we will say it is a taxonomy, because `categories` is a default taxonomy if you do not specify any in your site config.

The first thing we do is get a collection of the pages that have a category with a value of `photography`

```
 {{ $photography := .Site.Taxonomies.categories.photography  }}
```

Then we have to find a way to get the pages that have featured `true` by using the function `GroupByParam` and group by `featured`

```
{{ range ($photography.Pages.GroupByParam "featured") }}

{{ end }}
```

The group within this range will return the `.Key` value of `.Params.featured` so we will check the value of each until it is `true`. After the group of featured is found, sort in the order you like and return the one (1) you want.

```
{{ if eq .Key true }}
  {{ range last 1 .Pages.ByDate }}
    // The `.` context here is a page. Use it accordingly
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

**Full Code Example (categories as a taxonomy)**

```
{{ $photography := .Site.Taxonomies.categories.photography  }}
{{ range ($photography.Pages.GroupByParam "featured") }}
  {{ if eq .Key true }}
    {{ range last 1 .Pages.ByDate }}
    // The `.` context here is a page. Use it accordingly
    {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

***NOTES:***

- The solution uses `ByDate` to sort in order, but [can use any valid page collection sorting](https://gohugo.io/templates/lists#order-content) to get the page you need using `first` or `last` accordingly.
- Make sure the values in the grouped param (`featured`) are same type (boolean in this case). They will not work properly if they are mixed. They will work if you make them string, but need to check for string `"true"`.
- If you want to use taxonomy but not have the pages build for them you can `disableKinds = ["taxonomy","taxonomyTerm"]` in your config file as [per Hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/taxonomies/#hugo-taxonomy-defaults).

Comment: Hi @talves thank you. i did test the code and it have no error, but nothing showed up, im using v0.36. i'm using quotes for "true", try romove the quotes but still the same

Comment: I know this code works, because I have it working in production. Also working with 0.36 of Hugo. You may want to have it print out some values to the page in between the ranges to see what you are getting back. Also use `-v` option on the command for verbose warnings and errors.

Comment: ah my fault, I have to re run hugo server after change/edit the content params featured form "true" to true. quotes make the params ignored.  Thank you

Comment: Yeah, that is something I got wrong on my first attempt and is why I included it in the notes. Glad it worked :)